# How to find out the exact path of network shared files

Tags: file, networking, directory, shared-directory

I am having a little doubt about where actually the network shared files are saved. I am accessing some files with a path like "\\servername\folder\folder\file". But I tried to find these files in the server's drive, say c: and e:. But couldn't find those files in both the drives.

I am totally confused or don't know, how these thing work. Kindly can anyone, pls help me on this.

Thanks
Jonathon

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly try to use

```
wmic /node:%computername% share
```

in command prompt to see all shared folders for your computer and their locations.
I know this post is old, but maybe it'll help someone else.